# Date picker daterange in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datepicker

In my laravel project, I have two datepickers which include **from** and **to** dates.

When the **from date** is selected, I want to **disable** the dates before the from date's and let the user to select the **to date** after the selected from date.

In briefly, from date is **earlier date** and **to date** should be a later date.

Here is the code in blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><label for="date">From:</label><input type="text" class="datefrom" id="datefrom" name="datefrom" value="{{ old('datefrom') }}" />
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><label for="date">To:</label><input type="text" class="dateto" id="dateto" name="dateto" value="{{ old('dateto') }}" />
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('.datefrom').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1985,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    maxDate: new Date,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10),
    locale: {
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
            } 
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
  },

    $('.dateto').datepicker(
            "change", {
            minDate: new Date($('.datefrom').val())
        });
});

$(function() {
  $('.dateto').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1985,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    maxDate: new Date,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10),
    locale: {
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
            } 
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
  },

   $('.datefrom').datepicker(
            "change", {
            maxDate: new Date($('.dateto').val())
        });
  });
</script>
```

I want the functionality as [http://jsfiddle.net/jjLhca9o/5/][1]. Though I tried by using ids and classes in many ways I failed. May I know where I have gone wrong.

I want to validate the Date picker as well. But, datepicker takes the default date as current date. As a solution for that, I suggested to keep the date field empty before input any date. I tried with `autoUpdateInput: false`. When I add it to the script, the date field keeps empty though I selected a date from the date picker.

I am new to coding. Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range), using date range.
After selecting "From" you can select in next box "To": The "From" date is moved as parameter to next box, and you get the limits you want.
It easy to use and you can see full example in the link.

```
  $( function() {
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
  from = $( "#from" )
    .datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on( "change", function() {
       //Here we get the date and set as 'minDate' and update for next selection
      to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
    }),
  to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
    //Using 'to' box we set end limit, so 'to' box will be limited.
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
  });

//using that function you can get the range user picked
function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
    date = null;
  }

  return date;
 }
} );
```